# Hi can I show user status when he or she is online or vice-versia using firebase in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

How can I show user status when he or she is online or vice-versa using firebase? Can you give me sample project or app example where it was implemented in android?

Comment: check [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0).

Comment: @AbhayKoradiya, I want to implement other things but thank you for link

Answer (score 0):

A simple way in which you can achieve this, is to create a new node in your Firebase database to hold all online users, so when the user opens the application, you'll immediately add his id to this new created node. Then, if you want to check if the user is online, just check if his particular id exist beneath that node.

Another approach would be to add a new property named `isOnline` for each user in your database and then use it accordingly. For this, I recommend you to use Firebase's built-in `onDisconnect()` method. It enables you to predefine an operation that will happen as soon as the client becomes `disconnected`.

See [Firebase documentation for presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/offline-capabilities#section-presence).

You can also detecting the connection state of the user. For many presence-related features, it is useful for your app to know when it is `online` or `offline`. Firebase Realtime Database provides a special location at:

```
/.info/connected`
```

Which is updated every time the Firebase realtime Database client's connection state changes. Here is an example also from the official documentation:

```
DatabaseReference connectedRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(".info/connected");
    connectedRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            boolean connected = snapshot.getValue(Boolean.class);
            if (connected) {
                System.out.println("connected");
            } else {
                System.out.println("not connected");
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
            System.err.println("Listener was cancelled");
        }
});
```

Comment: I tried it but it is not working for me ,  i don't know how to make it work , i'm actually removing onDisconnect() value on app start ( makes user online) and when app is ondestroy i m calling onDisconenct.setValue()